# Privacy violation vulnerability issue

Tags: java, eclipse, fortify

I have the below constructor for my customized exception

```
public CoException(String errorMessage) {
    super(errorMessage);
    CoDebugger.debugException(errorMessage, this);
}
```

A static code analyzer tool (fortify) identifies vulnerability issue in this portion of code. 
The message given by fortify is 
"The method CoException() in CoException.java mishandles confidential information, which can compromise user privacy and is often illegal."

Please let me know where is the issue and how to fix that.

Comment: Why did you post 2 questions on basically the same topic (fortify privacy violation) within 10 minutes?

Comment: You've shown us the method `CoException(String)` not `CoException()`, so I doubt anyone can realistically answer your question.

Comment: @Thomas In earlier question there are 2 issues but code is almost same, whereas here code is different and I didnt want to make that question too long

Comment: Re @Thomas' point: It would likely be prudent to wait for and understand the answer to your first question on the topic, and then ask the second **if** it's still something you're not clear on.

Comment: @JonK Its a parameterized constructor . Issue exists in this constructor only not in the default one. So i  have posted only this

Comment: That's not what the error message you posted says. Your error message is specifically mentioning the *no-args* constructor.

Comment: @JonK This tool always gives the method name without any parameters inside it

Answer (score 3):

The tool makes a [data flow analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis):

- **Incoming:** `String errorMessage` - What error message could contain interesting information for an attacker? Let me think. *Login failed: user=admin pwd=123456* would certainly be something that should be kept internally.
- **Outgoing:** `super(errorMessage);` and `CoDebugger.debugException(errorMessage, this);` - What does the *debugException* method? Does it show the error message directly to the user? That should not happen. Or is the error message written to a log file which under certain conditions (e. g. by an incorrect *.htaccess* configuration) can be accessed by the user. That should also not happen, of course.

Comment: CoDebugger.debugException(errorMessage, this) logs the error message. This has been used through out the application in "catch" blocks to log exceptions. Do you think its a vulnerability issue. If yes then how should we log the exceptions at the time of catching them.

Comment: It will only be a problem if both conditions are met: incoming data to be protected and outgoing data that may accessible by an attacker. As long as only constant Strings are used as error messages, logging should not be a problem (e. g. `throw new FooException("Login failed");` instead of `throw new FooException("Login failed: " + name + "/" + pwd);`).